# Как экспортировать макет в Zeplin?

Tags: css, веб-дизайн, photoshop

Установил zeplin, дальше создаю проект и иду в фотошоп, создаю Артбоард и импортирую его через плагин, но мне пишет такое:
"Can't import artboards to "Untitled"
Only the project owner can upload designs under a "Free" plan, please contact the owner (xonar)."

Я зашёл в зеплин под своим логином, но экспортировать через плагин не даёт. На сайте зеплина и в гоше ничего не нашёл по этой ситуации. Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Как решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проект создать в Zeplin нужно.
Создаете проект, выбираете Web, потом выбираете фотошоп.
На Free плане, вы можете создавать только 1 проект под своим логином.

Comment: @ANYWAYCODE, само собой я это сделал в первую очередь.

Comment: Решили вопрос? Такая же история

Comment: @GlebBorovikov, в программе зеплин нажмите обновить плагин в левом углу  где меню и т.д.

Comment: У вас получилось решить проблему? Столкнулась с тем же самым и ничего из вышеперечисленного не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы решить эту проблему, нужно в Зеплин в левом углу в меню выбрать обновление плагина и обновиться. Перезапустить фотошоп и зеплин.